# How to calculate a value times another value?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to convert the value of an invoice so that value times another amount for an AMEX calculation as below. Something is missing as the answer being calculated is 0.

```
Sub AMEX()
Dim Number_1 As Integer
Dim Number_2 As Integer
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim strBillAmt As Integer

Dim intNumLines As Integer

'Get the Bill amount from the doc
strBillAmt = GetValue("[BillAmt]")

Do
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[AMEX]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Number_1 = 1.0175
            Number_2 = strBillAmt
            Answer = Number_1 * Number_2

        Selection.InsertFormula Formula:="Answer"

     Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of strbillamount just before the calculation is done?

Comment: The bill value changes with each bill and is output by accounting software. The amount is collected by the Get Value line

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working as below:

```vb
Sub AMEX()
Dim Number_1 As Integer, Number_2 As Integer
Dim Answer As Integer, strBillAmt As Integer
Dim strAMEXAmt As String

'Get the bill amount from the document
strBillAmt = GetValue("[BillAmt]")

    If Selection.Find.Execute("[AMEX]", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop) Then
        AMEXAmt = strBillAmt * 1.0175
        Selection.TypeText Format(AMEXAmt, "$#,##0.00")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are declaring `strBillAmt` as Integer, so it should be `intBillAmt`. Nevertheless, you should only use integers for money amounts if you are storing them as a cents expression ($57.85 would then be an integer = 5785). The format you're applying tells us you are not doing this. Therefore, you should use a floating point unit or else your fractions will be pruned with type conversion.